# How to add new field in array of arrays in angular5

Tags: angular

I am getting response from my database is like this

```
content:Array
0:Object
title:"title1"
content:"content1"
illustrations:Array
0:Object
title:"someTitle"
imagePath:"1.jpg"
```

Here I want to add one randomId in illustrations array. like this

```
illustrations:Array
    0:Object
    title:"someTitle"
    imagePath:"1.jpg"
    randomId:54321
```

I tried like this

```
var randid=Math.random()*900000
            var rand=Math.round(randid)
this.illustrations[i]=Object.assign({},this.illustrations[i],{randid:rand})
and also
this.illustrations[i]=Object.assign(this.illustrations[i],{randid:rand})
```

But not working.
Can any one please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
this.illustrations[i].randid = rand;
```

Comment: wired, it should. May be you can share more of your code like how you are creating and initializing the array illustrations and tell us what error/unexpected behaviour you are actually getting

Answer (score 0):

@Siva Goud..  give a try to this,

```
this.illustrations[i]['randomId'] = rand;
```

I hope this will work...   :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.illustrations[i]['randomId'] = rand;`?

Comment: actually no, because  `randid` is a variable.

Comment: According to OP the result should look like this `randomId: 54321`

Comment: this.illustrations[i]['randomId'] = rand;
the result looks like illustrations:53421.

Comment: it should work fine, any how provide clear JSON response to understand your requirement properly...